# Erro ao criar uma aplicação com create-react-app

Tags: react, cmd, app, create

Instalei o create-react-app tudo certinho, mas quando tentou criar um projeto usando o comando **create-react-app hello-world**  da o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\j.santos.da.silva\Desktop\curso-angular>create-react-app hello-world

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\j.santos.da.silva\Desktop\curso-angular\hello-world.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...verse":"7.0.0-alpha.1'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\j.santos.da.silva\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-12T15_34_51_173Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting hello-world / from C:\Users\j.santos.da.silva\Desktop\curso-angular
Done.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta de novo, parece ser apenas um problema de download, se não funcionar, tenta instalar uma dependência de cada vez para perceberes qual está a dar erro.

Tenta limpar a cache do npm, por vezes podes ter o mesmo erro repetidamente porque o ficheiro que causa o problema está em cache.

`npm cache clean --force`

Comment: cara deu certo, obrigado salvou minha manha tentando fazer isso rs